# Parse String to DateTime format "day, month dat, year"

Tags: c#, datetime

I have the following string which I need to parse into a date. 
Friday, Sept 23, 2016 – 3pm - 8pm

I split it on the n-dash and then I need to use `ParseExact` with a format string. I have tried the following. 
"dddd',' MMMM dd',' yyyy"
"dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy" 
"dddd MMMM dd yyyy"
"ddd, MMMM dd, yyyy"

I realize this is similar if not exact to long date but I need to be non local. 
Here is the function I made and am trying to use.

```
public DateTime parseDate(string s, string dateString)
{
    var splitAr = s.Split((char)8211);
    var dPart = new DateTime();
    try
    {
        dPart = DateTime.ParseExact(splitAr[0].Trim(), dateString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Trace.TraceWarning("Wasn't able to parse this date string so used try." + splitAr[0]);
        DateTime.TryParse(splitAr[0].Trim(), out dPart);
    }
    var timeArray = splitAr[1].Split('-');

    return d;
}
```

If anyone can see the issue I am pulling the string from a webpage I have scraped.

I tried to simplify it to be simple. I call it like this.

```
var result = objToTest.parseDate("Friday, Sept 23, 2016 – 3pm - 8pm", "dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy");
```

I only need the actual date not the 3pm-8pm because I have it being processed somewhere else since it is a range.

Thanks ahead of time

Comment: You will find it easier if you skip the day name as well as the time value, remove the commas and parse what's left a date. In your example that would be `Sept 23 2016`. You may find that the four-letter month abbreviation is a problem as it is not the expected abbreviation as in [DateTimeFormatInfo.AbbreviatedMonthNames](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.abbreviatedmonthnames(v=vs.110).aspx). Replacing with the full month name would solve that.

Comment: As @stuartd suggested, the reason you can't parse the date is because your string contains a 4-character month abbreviation (`Sept`). You must supply a 3-character month abbreviation. (Note though that `Sept` _could_ be a valid abbreviation for some locales. In other words, your code _may_ work if you use different `CultureInfo`, in which `Sept` is a valid abbreviation)

Comment: Why don't you post answers as answers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While writing the answer everything appeared in the comments (for some reason), but here is a working version you can test:

```
var str = "Friday, Sept 23, 2016 – 3pm - 8pm";

var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("en-US");
cultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedMonthNames = new[] 
    { "Jan", "Feb", "Mar",
      "Apr", "May", "Jun",
      "Jul", "Aug", "Sept",
      "Oct", "Nov", "Dec", "" };

var result = DateTime.ParseExact(str.Split('–').First().Trim(), "dddd, MMM dd, yyyy", cultureInfo);
```

Comment: Thank you so much this worked perfectly. Though I must ask why is there a 13th element in the array. I didn't even think about the 4 character abbreviation. Unfortunately I don't control the input. Is there a decent way to possibly include both 3 and 4 letter abbreviations? Or would I have to do 2 separate cultureInfos and do 2 attempts at the parse? Sorry if these questions shouldn't go here.

Comment: Sorry ignore the 13 element question as I finally found the right documentation.

Answer (score 2):

You were so close!

The problem was the months: `MMMM` is for spelling out the whole month name (`September` rather than `Sept`). Abbreviated month names like `Sept` use `MMM` with only 3 M's:

```
dddd, MMM dd, yyyy
```

[Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: This still didn't work due to the 4 character Sept abbreviation I was using.

Comment: Sorry but unless you can give me a reason for this to be the answer I won't change it. The other answer covers both this and also a fix for the 4 character abbreviation. This covers the issue for 1 M to many and that means the code still doesn't work.